# Getting a single-value estimation of trust in a computed mean

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have a number N of independent ratings of a given item, where each
rating is an integer between 1 and 7 (inclusive).  For simplicity sake,
let us assume the ratings are normally distributed, though the mean and
stddev will be different for each item.

I'm looking for a single number which will reflect how much trust I should 
put into the currently calculated mean.  As an example, if I have N=1000 
where every single rating is of 4, this trust should be pretty close to 100%.
If on the other hand I have only N=2 where one rating is 1 and the other is 7,
my trust that the mean is 4 should be very low.

I realise that a *compute-trust* function such as the one I've described 
above will likely need further parameterisation beyond the set of ratings.
If you prefer, I can reformulate *compute-trust* in terms of *"with 95%
confidence, what is the probability that the population mean will be found
within a given interval around the sample mean?"*

Any thoughts on how I can compute this trust in a manner that is statistically 
sound?

Edit: changed 'median' to 'mean'.

Comment: `the median and stddev will be different` Are you actually thinking of the median or the mean (expected value)?

Comment: Yes, I meant the "mean".  Sorry, English is not my first language.

Comment: Normality assumption is unreasonable. Do not understand meaning of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ being different "for each one." But put as a confidence interval problem, sample mean should, except for very small samples, have a normal enough distribution, and usual techniques will work well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, the [estimate of the standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Estimation) seems like a reasonable measure of the "trust" you can put in the mean.

Statistically speaking, you could consider the lengths of (say, 95%) [confidence intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) to measure that "trust". If the ratings are normally distributed, those lengths are proportional to the estimates of the standard deviation (see [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Theoretical_example)), so this would actually be the same measure.